# Using 7za from PowerShell with -xr option

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm using a PS script to compact a folder using 7za. If I use the -xr option to exclude some files the compression fails with a warning with items to compress equals to 0. If I run from Power Shell (not script) I get the same problem.

If I run the same command from command line all works fine. Also if I don't use the -xr flag the compression works.

```
PS d:\data> e:\backup\7za a -y e:\backup\data.7z * -xr!*.7z
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but be warned that 7za.exe is notoriously bad at parsing command line arguments, because it uses dubious home-made custom code to parse the command line (see NCommandLineParser::SplitCommandLine() in 7-Zip source code). I've been bit by that in the past. I would recommend writing your script in such a way as to ensure your 7za command line is as simple and straightforward as possible (perhaps by "staging" the files into a separate directory beforehand), otherwise you're asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powershell (!) is a reserved character denoting not/negation.

```
PS C:\> $true
True
PS C:\> !$true
False
```

Within CMD (!) has no special meaning
Within CMD I can run the following and it works:

```
7za.exe a -y .\test.7z .\* -xr!*.exe
```

Within Powershell the following gives an error:

```
.\7za.exe a -y .\test.7z .\* -xr!*.exe
<extra lines removed>
.exe:  WARNING: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Within PS, I was able to pass an argument that uses (!) by surrounding it with single quotes, which force the contents to be treated as literal.

```
.\7za.exe a -y .\test.7z .\* '-xr!*.exe'
```

Don't try to put $var inside single quotes, it will not expand.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
try{
   & "e:\backup\7za" a -y "e:\backup\data.7z" * -xr!*.7z
}catch{
   Write-Error $_;
}finally{
   Write-Host "check if error and continue";
}
```

it's work for me.
one line:

```
PS> try{ & "e:\backup\7za" a -y "e:\backup\data.7z" * -xr!*.7z; }catch{  Write-Error $_;  }finally{ Write-Host "check if error and continue";  }
```

You are **missing '&'** before your command.
More infos here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx#reCodeBlock , Chapter 5.

Comment: `You must ask questions related to programming on stackoverflow , not serverfault.` There's no problem with this question being on Serverfault.